# How to make JPanel fill the entire JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, minecraft

I am making an UI in a `minecraft` plugin. Everything is working, except I have a `JPanel` and it doesn't fill the whole `JFrame`. So what I want is the `JPanel` fill the entire `JFrame` even if we re-scale the window.

- I use Layout manager (`FlowLayout`) for the `JPanel`.
- I tried using a Layout manager for the `JFrame`, well it didn't solved my problem because it didn't resize the `JPanel`.. I tried setting the size of the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`'s size, but when it's resized it doesn't scale with it.

So, how can I do this?

My plugin creates a button for every player and when I click the button it kicks the player.

My code (I can't really post less because I don't know where I need to change something):

```
public static JFrame f;
public static JTextField jtf;
public static JPanel jp;

public static void creategui()
{

    System.out.println("GUI created.");
    f = new JFrame("Players");
    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    jp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    jtf = new JTextField("Reason");
    jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
    jtf.setToolTipText("Write the reason here.");
    jp.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    jp.add(jtf);f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    for (final Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())
    {
        System.out.println("Looping.");
        final JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setName(p.getName());
        b.setText(p.getName());
        b.setToolTipText("Kick " + b.getText());
        b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                {
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(main, new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Bukkit.getPlayer(b.getText()).kickPlayer(jtf.getText());
                            b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
        jp.add(b);
        System.out.println("Button added.");
    }
    f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Comment: `JPanel` usually takes the size of the components it contains. The default layout manager is `FlowLayout` so if you explicitly set the layout manager to `FlowLayout` you haven't changed anything. `JFrame` has a [content pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane--) which is usually `JPanel` with [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). Maybe you can post your code?

Answer (score 2):

The question should include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducing the problem so we can test it. 
It could look like this :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Mcve {

    private static List<String> players = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Player A", "Player B"});

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creategui();
    }

    public static void creategui()
    {

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Reason");
        jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
        jtf.setToolTipText("Write the reason here.");
        jp.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        jp.add(jtf);

        for (final String p : players)
        {
            final JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setText(p);
            b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            b.addActionListener(e -> {
                if (!b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                {
                  b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            });
            jp.add(b);
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Players");
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To make the `JPanel` fill the entire frame simply **remove** this line :

```
f.setLayout(null);
```

and let the default `BorderLayout` manager do its work.

Here is a modified version with some additional comments:

```
public class Mcve {

    private static List<String> players = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Player A", "Player B"});

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creategui();
    }

    public static void creategui()
    {

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("Reason");
        jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,20));
        jtf.setToolTipText("Write the reason here.");
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,200)); // set preferred size rather than size 
        jp.add(jtf);

        for (final String p : players)
        {
            final JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setText(p);
            b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            b.addActionListener(e -> {
                if (!b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                {
                  b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                }
            });
            jp.add(b);
        }

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Players");
        //f.setLayout(null);  null layouts are bad practice 
        //f.setSize(500,500); let layout managers set the sizes 
        f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A 1x1 grid layout does the job quite nicely.

```
window = new JFrame();
panel = new JPanel();
window.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 1));
window.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set the layout manager for `jp` (the `JPanel` in the code you posted) to `BorderLayout` and add `jtf` (the `JTextField` in the code you posted) to the CENTER of `jp`, as in:

```
f = new JFrame();
jp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
jtf = new JTextField(30); // number of columns
jp.add(jtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

or dispense with `jp` and add `jtf` directly to `f` (the `JFrame` in the code you posted), as in:

```
f = new JFrame();
jtf = new JTextField(30);
f.add(jtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The key is that the CENTER component of `BorderLayout` expands to fill the available space.

Comment: So, this is my code now: https://pastebin.com/6Ci3mJ8J and it is not showing anything in the frame. Not even the Jpanel.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it somehow, this is the code:

```
public static void creategui()
{

    System.out.println("GUI created.");
    f = new JFrame("Players");
    jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    jp.setSize(200,200);
    jtf = new JTextField(30);
    jtf.setToolTipText("Write the reason here.");

    jp.add(jtf);
    for (final Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())
    {
        System.out.println("Looping.");
        final JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setName(p.getName());
        b.setText(p.getName());
        b.setToolTipText("Kick " + b.getText());
        b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                {
                    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(main, new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            getplr(b.getText()).kickPlayer(jtf.getText());
                            b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
        jp.add(b);
        System.out.println("Button added.");
    }

    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Calling `pack()` after `setSize()` just makes Swing ignore that `setSize()` call, so you can safely remove it. `JFrame` uses `BorderLayout` by default, so, you can remove this line as well: `f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());`.

Comment: So I need to remove pack or setSize ?

Comment: You need to remove `setSize`